# debug native ndk objects in Android studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, adb

I'm unable to add breakpoints, evaluate expressions or expand collections for my ndk objects.

While android objects like Fragments and Adapters can be expanded, ndk objects don't.

How do I expand and see the contents of the "list" collection shown in the image.

[image: debug pic]

Comment: what do you mean by `ndk objects`? the view you posted is taken from debugging your java part, right?

Comment: native objects written in C

Comment: the view you posted is taken from debugging your java part, right? so what is `list` object (BookList@6596)?

Comment: Yes, it's the debugger screenshot, BookList is a native C object collection not a java object collection.

Comment: BookListFragment is also a native C object?

Comment: actually, it's an instance of a regular Android fragment

Comment: so the view you posted is taken while debugging java or native part of your code?

Comment: The breakpoint is in java, in one of the app's Activity.

Comment: so how do you want to inspect native c objects while debugging java part of your application? step into the native c code and you will be able to do that